# application for iPhone to read bar codes

Tags: software-recommendation, applications, iphone

I need to read different bar codes, and would be great that I can use my iPhone for that.  Currently I have an application to read QRCodes but I'm looking to read PDF417 too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use
RedLaser for "normal" codes and [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/index.html) for QRCodes.

These are the fastest and most stable I could find. Plus, they are both free.

Comment: RedLaser vs Barcode Scanner, how do you decide?

Answer (score 3):

[Red Laser](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/redlaser/id312720263?mt=8) has just updated to read more types of barcode. Plus it's free.

Comment: Why do I hear RedLaser everywhere these days? Is it the default app for QR reading now?